# Transitioning from Walk Cycle

Tags: animation

I need to have a character take a slow walk through different areas of large scene.I'll be using a walkcycle for most of it.  Imagine your in a house walking slowly from one room to another.  You would be at rest position... then begin the walk to the next room where you would then come to another rest.

There a many walk cycle tutorials, but I have yet to see on where the character transitions to a stop or goes from a stop into the walkcycle.
I'll be using Blenders video editor most likely.

Can someone describe how this is properly done? If anyone has ever done this, Maybe you can post a blend file, so I could study how it is done.

Comment: Anybody have any ideas on the above?

Comment: It seems to me that you are literally asking how to animate at all, and unless you specify your need, the answer will always remains as "just key frame everything."

Comment: @SVAFnemesis He is not asking how to animate the walk itself, but how to repeatedly transition between walking and other movements without having to individually key each walking portion.

Comment: @JustWondering He didn't state "without having to individually key each walking portion." He did ask "how is this PROPERLY done". And as a working animator I still have to say: transition or not, key frame everything, for it IS the proper way. I also suspect that he is looking for the pose to pose technique, which is literally "how to animate at all".

Answer (score 1):

Use the Non-Linear Animation Editor.  First make an action of the character resting, standing or whatever you want him doing, then, having that strip set to 'Hold Forward' make another strip for the walk cycle.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have a sensor trigger an actuator to create another state.

The walking cycle would continue along a path until a delay sensor, ray cast or something similar triggers an actuator to create the resting state, then a delay sensor on the new state would trigger a new walking state and so forth.

The walking/resting action (animation) can be added to each relative state.

Comment: I suspect the OP is asking about animating this in the 3D view, not in the game engine